# It possible to run two lazy Modules with effectsmodule.forfeature for both of them?

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading, ngrx

It possible to run two lazy Modules with effectsmodule.forfeature for both of them?

I want load same `effectsmodule.forfeature('example')` on difference modules as lazy
without load it (effectsmodule.forfeature('example')) twice.

Both modules isn't brothers so don't have any parent module to implement it easly.

It possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. First, you should create an angular module for **example** store - example.store.module.ts. It looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { exampleReducer, ExampleEffects } from "../example/store";
import { EffectsModule } from "@ngrx/effects";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ExampleEffects]),
    StoreModule.forFeature("example", exampleReducer),
  ]
})
export class ExampleStoreModule { }
```

After that, you can import this **ExampleStoreModule** to multiple lazy-loaded modules in your application

example 1: first lazy-loaded module

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ExampleStoreModule,
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [
       ...
      ],
      providers: [
       ...
      ]
    })
    export class FisrtModule { }
```

example 2: second lazy-loaded module

```
        @NgModule({
          imports: [
            CommonModule,
            ExampleStoreModule,
            ...
          ],
          declarations: [
           ...
          ],
          providers: [
           ...
          ]
        })
        export class SecondModule { }
```

Comment: Your ExampleStoreModule looklike as shared module, I mean with ExampleStoreModule he same like firstmodule & second module. second You can just import taht lines `    EffectsModule.forFeature([ExampleEffects]),
    StoreModule.forFeature("example", exampleReducer),` but it feel like too many injections it should be like that? as best practice